# Filter IN and OUT swipes in day and night shift attendance shift?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am developing an attendance system which has a day and a night shift. I am unable to filter the IN and OUT punches of the employees?

For shift timings on:

- 29-Jun-2013, IN 22:00,  OUT 07:00
- 30-Jun-2013, IN 15:00, OUT 22:30

This is my current logic:

I am filtering the IN and OUT punches based on the shift timings and swipe time along with date, but when the employee changes from the night shift to the day shift I am getting a problem.

The below is the one scenario

The employee, 101, has worked on 29-Jun-2013 on the night shift punched at 22:00 and he left at next day means 30-Jun-2013 07:00 AM. Again, on the same day, (30-Jun-2013) he came to office at 15:00 on 30-Jun-2013 and he left at 22:30 on the same day.

If the punches will come daily then there is no problem, however due to any problem punches are not received for 30-Jun-2013 07:00 AM then the punches IN 15:00 OUT 22:30 on 30-Jun-2013 already in database now the out punch of 29-Jun-2013 is 30-Jun-2013 at 07:00 AM it is difficult to find this as previous day out punch

Note: some times the employees forgot to swipe IN/OUT punch

How should I do this?

**Update:**

we don't the know the which type of punch it is either IN or OUT until unless I need to compare with shift timings then only I can decide it however when employee changing from night shift to day shift then last day of the night shift and first day of the day shift IN and OUT are coming wrong because 29-Jun-13 night shift he will come at 22:00 and he left at 30-jun-13 07:00 and again he came to office on 30-jun-13 at 15:00 and OUT is 22:30 now for 30-Jun-13 I have three punches, here punches may come into db different ways first IN time of 30-Jun-13 will come or OUT time of 29-Jun-13 will come or OUT time of 30-jun-13 will come so here I am getting problem

Comment: This is your current logic and your current logic is incorrect? Could you tell us what you'd like to do and post the code you've got so far in order to do this. Could you also provide some sample data, the end result and the DDL of the table the sample data is in.

Answer (score 0):

You need more information than just the time of the punch.  I suggest you maintain the current status of the employee ('IN', 'OUT', or 'ERROR').  Then, when a punch is received perform the following:

```
1.  If the employee status is ERROR:
    A. Record the punch as an ERROR which must be addressed by a supervisor.

2.  If the employee is IN:
    A. If the time since the last punch is greater than the max number of hours
       an employee is allowed to work consecutively
       i.  Flag the punch as an ERROR which must be addressed by a supervisor.
       ii. Change the status of the employee to ERROR.
    B. Otherwise:
       i. Treat this as an OUT punch.
       ii.  Change the status of the employee to OUT.

3.  If the employee is OUT:
    A. Treat this as an IN punch.
    B. Change the status of the employee to IN.
```

You'll need to provide a Supervisor Clock Maintenance app to allow supervisors to update the status of employees and punches, and to delete or add punches as necessary.

Comment: we don't the know the which type of punch it is either IN or OUT until unless I need to compare with shift timings then only I can decide it however when night shift came here I am getting problem because

Answer (score 0):

Considering your table for punch dates as :

```
emp_punch_time (empno, punch_time)
```

This table only stores empno (i.e., employee number) and punch_time (including date and time).

In this case, you can do something like following:

```
WITH emp_punch_time AS (
-- This common table expression is just for your illustration.
-- When using this query on your base tables remove this CTE and make
-- appropriate changes to the subsequent queries.
SELECT 7369 AS empno
       , TO_DATE('29-JUN-2013 22:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') punch_time
  FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7369, TO_DATE('30-JUN-2013 07:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7369, TO_DATE('30-JUN-2013 15:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7369, TO_DATE('30-JUN-2013 22:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7370, TO_DATE('29-JUN-2013 07:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7370, TO_DATE('29-JUN-2013 15:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7370, TO_DATE('29-JUN-2013 22:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7370, TO_DATE('30-JUN-2013 07:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual
)
, punch AS (
SELECT p.empno
       , p.punch_time
       , CASE MOD(row_number() over (partition by empno
                                         order by p.punch_time asc), 2)
            WHEN 1 THEN 'IN'
            ELSE 'OUT'
         END AS punch_type
  FROM emp_punch_time p)
, punch_repo AS (
SELECT p.empno
       , p.punch_time AS in_time
       , (SELECT punch_time
            FROM punch p_out
           WHERE p_out.punch_type = 'OUT'
             AND p_out.empno = p.empno
             AND p_out.punch_time = (SELECT MIN(punch_time)
                                       FROM punch p_min
                                      WHERE p_min.punch_type = 'OUT'
                                        AND p_min.empno = p_out.empno
                                        AND p_min.punch_time > p.punch_time))
         AS out_time
  FROM punch p
 WHERE punch_type = 'IN'
)
SELECT empno
       , TO_CHAR(in_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') in_time
       , TO_CHAR(out_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') out_time
       , TRIM(TO_CHAR(FLOOR((out_time - in_time) * 24), '09'))
         ||':'
         || TRIM(TO_CHAR(FLOOR(MOD((out_time - in_time)*24, 1) * 60), '09'))
         AS time_spent
  FROM punch_repo
;
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
  EMPNO   IN_TIME                 OUT_TIME                TIME_SPENT
  7369    29-JUN-2013 22:00:00    30-JUN-2013 07:00:00    09:00
  7369    30-JUN-2013 15:00:00    30-JUN-2013 22:30:00    07:30
  7370    29-JUN-2013 07:00:00    29-JUN-2013 15:00:00    08:00
  7370    29-JUN-2013 22:00:00    30-JUN-2013 07:00:00    09:00
```